# How to fix No such file or directory in Android

Tags: java, android, file, encryption

In my application i have **Decrypt** file with **AES256** and **CBC** . 
i have written  below codes, to check if file exists.
But when run application it shows me an error and not can open my file!
I used Log.e to show files's path and it shows me this path. but it says can not open file!

**My code :**

```
    private SecureRandom r;
    private byte[] _iv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    r = new SecureRandom();
    _iv = new byte[16];
    r.nextBytes(_iv);

String inputFile = getRootDirPath(context) + "/"+bookName;
                String outPutFile = getRootDirPath(context) + "/BookFile_716798_decrypt3.html";

                File file = new File(inputFile);
                if (file.exists()) {
                    try {
                        decrypt(inputFile, encryptionPassword, outPutFile, "");
                        Log.e("DecryptLog", "0");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("DecryptLog", "1 : " + e.getMessage());
                        Log.e("DecryptLog", "\nPath : " + inputFile);
                    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("DecryptLog", "2 : " + e.getMessage());
                    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("DecryptLog", "3 : " + e.getMessage());
                    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("DecryptLog", "4 : " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Not", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
}

    public String getRootDirPath(Context context) {
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
            File file = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    null)[0];
            return file.getAbsolutePath();
        } else {
            return context.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
        }
    }

    private void decrypt(String path, String password, String _initVector, String outPath)
            throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outPath);
        byte[] key = (password).getBytes("UTF-8");
        MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        key = sha.digest(key);
        key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
        SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");

        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks, new IvParameterSpec(_iv));
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
        int b;
        byte[] d = new byte[8];
        while ((b = cis.read(d)) != -1) {
            fos.write(d, 0, b);
        }
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        cis.close();
    }
```

After run application show me this **error** :

```
2020-08-01 08:03:59.324 28560-28560/com.app.appE/DecryptLog: 1 : : open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2020-08-01 08:03:59.324 28560-28560/com.app.app E/DecryptLog: Path : /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.app.app/files/BookFile_716798.html
```

Comment: have you added read external storage permission ? have you added Runtime permission check for Android 6+?

Comment: @kelvin, yes my friend. first i download file from server and store this into my folder! then Decrypt this!!

Comment: `catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }` You should display a Toast there to inform the user and yourself. And then return as it makes no sense to continue. Make it private boolean decrypt() so you can return false so the caller knows that all went ok or wrong. Make your code robust. Or rethrow that exception too.